# anchor automatically change width with background image

Tags: html, css

When I put a background image in my anchor, my anchor is changing it's width. Take a look at the result before the background () and after insert a background image

http://s17.postimage.org/6xn7qci2l/tela.png

before: http://jsfiddle.net/jvN7z/8/

after: http://jsfiddle.net/jvN7z/7/

Comment: Hi I'm talking about the retangular white space at right of the colored retangulars.

Comment: Use `overflow:hidden` as pointed out by arttronics

Comment: Sorry, there was an error on my jsFiddle code. Take one that reproduces the exact problem. http://jsfiddle.net/jvN7z/7/

Comment: If is there any doubt about the question, please tell me that I'll make the best to be clear.

Comment: there is no white space on the right side of the rectangles

Comment: At right of red regangle, there is a white retangle. Inside of outlined li. If you remove my background image, like in the http://jsfiddle.net/jvN7z/8/ this white retangle is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the issue you were trying to show everybody:
[**jsFiddle issue**](http://jsfiddle.net/jvN7z/9/)

And if so, the solution is to change `width` to `auto` for the arrow image, or just remove `width` from that style.
[**jsFiddle fixed**](http://jsfiddle.net/jvN7z/10/)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Like you, I've changed to auto for anchor element, not the arrow image. Why this occur? Can you give me a little explanation of this problem?

Comment: It's because you are using `padding` with the image. Setting `width` to `100%` **will** cause the white rectangle to be seen when padding is used since that's part of the 100%.

Comment: But the padding is just for anchor element and image is in background. This only occur when I set the background image. Padding also considers background image?

Comment: `padding` is considered part of the space define, so in an indirect way yes it's part of the image. Especially true if your background image is actually color only because then it seemly makes the image larger. Learn more about `padding` [**HERE**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions).